# Empty translation files using QT internationalisation

Tags: qt, internationalization, translation

I am using QT and trying to generate .ts translation files using the **pylupdate4** command. 
I marked the strings I needed to translate with

```
     self.tr('example string')
```

Unfortuanetly, the generated **.ts** files are empty.

I am in the **src** folder of the project and generate my own **.pro** file, which is also in the **src** folder. It looks like this:

```
SOURCE = rob_gui.py 
TRANSLATIONS = en.ts \
    germ.ts
```

rob_gui.py is also in the src folder.

Why are the **.ts** files empty?

Comment: It’s `SOURCES` not `SOURCE`. Try again with SOURCES in case that wasn’t a typo here.

Comment: Hey..yeah that was it. Could you maybe tell me how to neatly include all the files from my project for translation?

Comment: Add them all to SOURCES, I think. You could use wildcards if you don't want to list them explicitly: `SOURCES += $$files(*.py)`